# Add focus to camera flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application written on a flutter in which I take a photo, turn this photo into a base64 and then send. But I have a problem I can't focus on the camera. So I'm new to flutter, I can't solve this problem myself. I will be grateful for your help. My goal is to focus on that place when you tap the screen.
Here is my code:

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class PicturePreview extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;
  const PicturePreview(this.camera, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PicturePreviewState createState() => _PicturePreviewState();
}
class _PicturePreviewState extends State<PicturePreview> {
  late CameraController _controller;
  Future<void>? _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  late String _imageB64;
  late File  _image;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.low,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();
            _image = File(image.path);
            List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
            _imageB64 = base64Encode(imageBytes);
            Navigator.pop(context, _imageB64);
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no focus functionality in the camera package. You should implement it yourself or try [adv_camera package](https://pub.dev/packages/adv_camera).

Here is a simple example:

```
import 'package:adv_camera/adv_camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  String id = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(id: id)));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('Press Floating Button to access camera')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "test3",
        child: Icon(Icons.camera),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                String id = DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
                return CameraApp(id: id);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  const CameraApp({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  List<String> pictureSizes = <String>[];
  String? imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AdvCamera Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AdvCamera(
          initialCameraType: CameraType.rear,
          onCameraCreated: _onCameraCreated,
          onImageCaptured: (String path) {
            if (this.mounted)
              setState(() {
                imagePath = path;
              });
          },
          cameraPreviewRatio: CameraPreviewRatio.r16_9,
          focusRectColor: Colors.purple,
          focusRectSize: 200,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "capture",
        child: Icon(Icons.camera),
        onPressed: () {
          cameraController!.captureImage();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  AdvCameraController? cameraController;

  _onCameraCreated(AdvCameraController controller) {
    this.cameraController = controller;

    this.cameraController!.getPictureSizes().then((pictureSizes) {
      setState(() {
        this.pictureSizes = pictureSizes ?? <String>[];
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but when I decided to start the camera with your example, I had a problem (const CameraApp) (super (key? key, required this.id}): super (key: key);) required this.id - here it arose error.

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк I changed the example. It should work now

Comment: strange, but in this part of the code and there was an error (required this.id). 12 line

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк Could you rephrase your message? Are you still getting the error with the updated code?

Comment: yes)error in 12 lines of code ,namely in the part "required this.id". ERROR INFO (The parameter type 'dynamic' is incompatible with the field type 'String'.  Try changing or removing the parameter's type, or changing the field's type)

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк Can you show the full code? Since there cannot be such an error in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234841/discussion-between---and-yuri-heiko).

Comment: hello, I added a screenshot of my code to the chat, did you see?)

Comment: Hello, did you have time to look at my code?)

Comment: hello, I finally returned to this issue, I updated the version of the SDK, but now you can run everything on the latest version, without any problems (but through the command flutter run --no-sound-null-safety), I will be grateful if you can take the time for my question)

Comment: Hi, you probably forgot to push your changes

Comment: I updated the code in my question, this code that I have now)

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк does it still not work? If yes I would need you to update your repository to figure out what is going on there.

Comment: yes, I updated everything in myself not a hit hub, everything works (but you need to run without zero security). But there was a problem, the package which advised "adv_camera", it blocks scanning of a bar code (after the beginning of scanning the application is buried and knocks out an error)

Comment: I tried to apply the second package to scan the barcode, but the same error . when i delete the package, adv camera, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

The [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) is bareback plugin, where most camera functions are meant to be self implemented. They have exposed all the basic functions such as `setFocusPoint`, `setFlashMode` etc for developers.

For the focus implementation part you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968038/how-to-implement-tap-to-focus-in-flutter-camera-plugin) StackOverflow post.

However, for your usecase I wouldn't suggest to go with [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) or [adv_camera](https://pub.dev/packages/adv_camera) packages. If you simply want to capture a picture with the default provided camera by the Android System with all the functionalities, best go with [Image-Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package. This will make your life easy.